# Symfony LDAP Provider credentials

Tags: php, symfony

I have a php / Symfony 2 app that is using LDAP authentication. I want to use the same login credentials to log the user into another web site that uses authentication from the same Active Directory. In my controller, I know I can do something like this to get the logged in user:

```
$loggedInUser = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

I can see the username. But, I can not see the password. That is probably a good thing. But, without the password, I am not sure I know how to log the user in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is really an answer, but, I decided to take a different approach with this. I re-prompt the user for their password. That made the most sense for me.